# Html input field set maximum value

Tags: javascript, html, input

the max property does not work if i put a number in the field. Why?
it works only when i change the value with the arrows.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usdc3359/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input id= "0" class='labelmax form-control'  
type='number' name='max_label' min='0' max='99' value='1'>
```

Comment: When you put this in a form, it will not submit if you typed in a value outside of the min and max values.

Comment: see your ja fiddle i edited: it works on submit ittl give error id more then 99: https://jsfiddle.net/usdc3359/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HTML5 max and min, you can only restrict the values to enter numerals. But you need to use JavaScript or jQuery to do this kind of change. One idea I have is using data- attributes and save the old value:

```
$(function () {
  $("input").keydown(function () {
    // Save old value.
    $(this).data("old", $(this).val());
  });
  $("input").keyup(function () {
    // Check correct, else revert back to old value.
    if (parseInt($(this).val()) <= 99 && parseInt($(this).val()) >= 0)
      ;
    else
      $(this).val($(this).data("old"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For it work automatically you have to wrap your input within a form and add a submit button to that form

If you don't want to wrap it in a form and want maximum customisation  you'll have to use Javascript and setup an event handler that will listen for user input and act accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below by making use of simple JavaScript. In your code I dont see any JS.

```js
 document.getElementsByClassName('labelmax form-control')[0].oninput = function () {
        var max = parseInt(this.max);

        if (parseInt(this.value) > max) {
            this.value = max; 
        }
    }
```

```html
<input id= "0" class='labelmax form-control'  type='number' name='max_label'  max='99' value='1'/>
```

Comment: I'm still able to type in numbers lower than 0, though. You should include checking the min value aswell.